# 3D Camera Rotation causes object to stretch

Tags: java, camera, rotation, rotational-matrices

I am trying to write a 3D java engine and I have been trying to implement camera rotation for a week now but I am facing a problem : The objects turn around but not in the normal manner. They get stretched and don't rotate around me.

Source : https://github.com/MathIsSimple/3D

I am using this project as a basis https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/videos/blob/master/OneLoneCoder_olcEngine3D_Part3.cpp

Without camera rotation : [image]
WIth camera rotation : [image]

Thanks!